# How to differentiate single view with multiple viewModels with different styles in MVVM swift

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

Lets consider,

I am having a view that has common structure but different styles for buttons and textviews.

I am accessing view different viewModels.

View Model 1: While accessing the view with this model 1, styles of the button and textviews should change.

View Model 2: While accessing the view with this model 2, styles of the button and textviews should change.

What approach should we use to change styles in view corresponding scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The view is responsible for its style, so there should be no style specifics in the model.

I see several options:

1. Implement both styles in the view and have a property (e.g. an enum with two cases) in both models to select either one.
2. Same as 1. but now create two styling logic parts and have a plain view that applies either one of the styles.
3. Have a view baseclass with a subclass for each of the two styles. Then instantiate either one of these subclasses.

Main goal should always be: Keep things simple and easy to understand.